# Draw a line between one particular pixel and a number of other pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot

I have a bw image which has a black background and contains a number of white pixels (like stars in night sky). First, one of these pixels is chosen, and its coordinates are saved in a **1*2** matrix named **FirstPixel**. Then, all the other pixels are one by one chosen. **Rows** and **Cols** are two **1*numel(find(pic))** matrices, containing X and Y coordinates of these pixels, respectively.
I want to draw a line between the first chosen pixel and all the other pixels, which mostly looks like beams of light being emitted from the origin **FirstPixel**.

I have written some codes using `plot`… but the answer was terribly wrong!
Like this:

```
pic = imread( 'interest points' );
figure, imshow ( pic );
hold on
plot([Rows (1,:)'  Cols (1,:)'],[FirstPixel (1,1)'  FirstPixel (1,2)'], 'r-');
```

any help?!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two arguments of 'plot' are X and Y values, not first and second points as you did. Also you need to give *numel* times your firstpixel, try with this :

```
NUMEL = numel(find(pic));
hold on
plot([Rows; ones(1,NUMEL)*FirstPixel(1)],[Cols; ones(1,NUMEL)*FirstPixel(2)],'-k');
```

Comment: This answer confused me quite a lot until I figured out that `Rows` in the question actually refers to the X-coordinates (which I personally find a bit backwards). Now I've got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `Rows` represent the x coordinates in the question (and `Cols` the y coordinates) can make the accepted answer a bit confusing.

I didn't know how to clarify this for future readers other than to make a new answer.

Here is a complete code example simulating the scenario in the question, but with `rows` representing the y coordinates and `cols` the x coordinates.

```
% replicate scenario (using 4 points)
I = uint8(zeros(256, 256));
I(124, 115) = 255;
I(139, 165) = 255;
I(12, 185) = 255;
I(124, 185) = 255;

n = numel(find(I));
[rows, cols] = ind2sub(size(I), find(I));
rows = rows';
cols = cols';
pixels = [rows; cols]';
firstPixel = pixels(1,:);

% show image and plot overlay
imshow(I);
hold on;
plot([cols; ones(1,n)*firstPixel(2)], [rows; ones(1,n)*firstPixel(1)], '-r');
```

Here is the resulting plot.

[image: lines_between_points]

I hope this helps future visitors who have this problem.

Comment: yes @mags, actually I DID make this change to the code to make it work in my case ... and it was my bad not to point it out for future readers. thanks for your clarification :)